# C++ и разбухание кода при инстанцировании шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, instance

Рассмотрим следующую ситуацию:

Имеется класс-шаблон `T`, который объявлен и определен в файле `t.hpp`.

Также имеется два других класса. Класс `A`, который объявлен в `a.hpp` и определен в `a.cpp`. Класс `B`, который объявлен в `b.hpp` и определен в `b.cpp`.

Допустим, и класс `A`, и класс `B` наследуются от одной и той же специализации класса-шаблона `T`:

```
class A : public T<int, 10>
{};

class B : public T<int, 10>
{};
```

Мои вопросы заключаются вот в чем:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что на этапе компиляции компилятор инстанцирует шаблон `T<int, 10>` и в `a.cpp`, и в `b.cpp`?
2. Даже если шаблон инстанцируется с одинаковыми параметрами в разных единицах трансляции, он ведь может порождать различный код? Включая различия в сигнатурах и искажениях имен. Ведь одни и те же на первый взгляд типы могут иметь некоторые отличия в разных единицах трансляции?
3. Если инстанцирование шаблона порождает один и тот же код в разных единицах трансляции, может ли линкер избавиться от одинакового кода? Ведь проблема заключается не только в том, что код раздувается, но еще и в том, что одинаковый код имеет разные адреса в памяти (те же методы), а это может иметь некоторые неожиданные последствия.

Comment: Линкер выбросит дублированный код. Но, вообще-то, так делать не рекомендуется. Это признак плохого проектирования. Инстанцировали шаблон, получили класс "a", и теперь пользуйтесь этим классом "a" во всех остальных единицах трансляции. Иначе, если придется изменить/добавить/убрать функциональность у класса "a", то Вам придется править и класс "a" и класс "b". Помните, что класс это тип, а тип надо определять в одном месте. Вот экземпляров типа может быть много, а само определение типа должно быть в одном месте. Потому, что так править удобнее.

Comment: 1. Да 2. Нет. Если код выходит разный в силу разного определения шаблонов, то это нарушение ODR и UB. 3. Среди inline определений линкер использует только одно.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, это всего лишь пример, чтобы было понятно, о чем я конкретно спрашиваю. Вместо наследования можно рассмотреть композицию, того же `std::vector<>`.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте проведем *эксперимент*.

Шаблон класса:

```
template<typename Protocol>
class basic_socket
{
public:
    explicit basic_socket(Protocol protocol);
    virtual ~basic_socket() = default;

protected:
    Protocol m_protocol;
};

template<typename Protocol>
inline basic_socket<Protocol>::basic_socket(Protocol protocol)
    : m_protocol(protocol)
{}
```

Наследник `tcp_socket`:

```
// tcp_socket.h

#include "tcp.h"
#include "basic_socket.hpp"

class tcp_socket : public basic_socket<tcp>
{
public:
    explicit tcp_socket(tcp protocol = tcp());
};

// tcp_socket.cc

tcp_socket::tcp_socket(tcp protocol)
    : basic_socket(protocol)
{}
```

Наследник `secure_tcp_socket`:

```
// secure_tcp_socket.h

#include "tcp.h"
#include "basic_socket.hpp"

class secure_tcp_socket : public basic_socket<tcp>
{
public:
    explicit secure_tcp_socket(tcp protocol = tcp());
};

// secure_tcp_socket.cc

secure_tcp_socket::secure_tcp_socket(tcp protocol)
    : basic_socket(protocol)
{}
```

main:

```
#include "tcp_socket.h"
#include "secure_tcp_socket.h"

auto main() -> int
{
    tcp_socket socket;
    secure_tcp_socket secure_socket;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Прошу прощение за эти "полотна" кода, но мне хочется чтобы были представлены все детали.

Компилируем и идем в директорию сборки, в которой среди прочих есть два объектных файла:

1. tcp_socket.cc.o
2. secure_tcp_socket.cc.o

С помощью nm посмотрим таблицы символов для каждого объектного файла. Здесь я буду использовать флаг `-m` для получения дополнительной информации о сегментах, секциях и прочей расширенной информации о каждом симоле.

Результат:

```
nm -m tcp_socket.cc.o | grep basic_socket

0000000000000040 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_
00000000000000f0 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED0Ev
00000000000000d0 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED1Ev
0000000000000120 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED2Ev
0000000000000170 (__DATA,__const) weak external __ZTI12basic_socketI3tcpE
00000000000001c5 (__TEXT,__const) weak external __ZTS12basic_socketI3tcpE
0000000000000198 (__DATA,__const) weak external automatically hidden __ZTV12basic_socketI3tcpE


nm -m secure_tcp_socket.cc.o | grep basic_socket

0000000000000040 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_
00000000000000f0 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED0Ev
00000000000000d0 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED1Ev
0000000000000120 (__TEXT,__text)  weak external automatically hidden __ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED2Ev
0000000000000170 (__DATA,__const) weak external __ZTI12basic_socketI3tcpE
00000000000001cc (__TEXT,__const) weak external __ZTS12basic_socketI3tcpE
0000000000000198 (__DATA,__const) weak external automatically hidden __ZTV12basic_socketI3tcpE
```

Как видите, каждый из символов помечен как "weak external". По-умолчанию, символ в объектном файле является *сильным* (strong), и если во время компоновки у вас оказалось два сильных символа с одинаковыми именами - это link-time error: для сильного символа компоновщик может "принять" только одно определение, в противном случае вы получите ошибку множественного определения. Для слабого же символа он примет любое количество определений и выберет одно.

---

Интересно, что под linux таблицы символов имеют следующий вид (пример для tcp_socket):

```
0000000000000000 W _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC1ES0_
0000000000000000 W _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_
0000000000000000 n _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC5ES0_
0000000000000000 W _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED0Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpED5Ev
0000000000000000 V _ZTI12basic_socketI3tcpE
0000000000000000 V _ZTS12basic_socketI3tcpE
0000000000000000 V _ZTV12basic_socketI3tcpE
```

, т.е. часть из них находится в read-only секции(ях) и каждый из них имеет нулевой отступ в соответствующей секции

---

Теперь давайте посмотрим link map и заодно попробует сделать trace для одного из символов (g++ под macOS говорит, что ни о каких --trace-symbol он не знает, так что я вынужден пересесть за linux, если кто-то знает в чем дело - прошу рассказать).

Для генерации link map выполним следующую команду:

`g++ -o app main.o tcp_socket.o secure_tcp_socket.o \
    -Wl,--trace-symbol='_ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_',-M=app.map`

Вывод:

> tcp_socket.o: definition of _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_
>   secure_tcp_socket.o: reference to _ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_

Как видите, несмотря на то, что данный символ (сответствует basic_socket::basic_socket(tcp)) определен в таблицах символов обоих объектных файлов, определен он именно в tcp_socket.o.

Заглянем в link map:

```
.text._ZN12basic_socketI3tcpEC2ES0_
0x0000000000000b68       0x19 tcp_socket.o
0x0000000000000b68       basic_socket<tcp>::basic_socket(tcp)
0x0000000000000b68       basic_socket<tcp>::basic_socket(tcp)
```

Символ определен там, где и ожидалось.

---

Касательно вопроса #3.

1. Жадное инстанцирование
   При жадном инстанцировании предполагается, что компоновщик уведомлен о том, что некоторые объекты могут дублироваться в разных объектных файлах. Когда компоновщик обнаруживает множественное инстанцирование, одно из них он оставляет, остальные - отбрасываются.
2. Инстанцирование по запросу
   При таком типе инстанцирования создается репозиторий, который используется при компиляции всех единиц трансляции. Туда помещается информация об инстанцированных специализациях шаблона и той части исходного кода, от которой они зависят. Сгенерированные специализации шаблона так же храняться в этом репозитории.
3. Итеративное инстанцирование
   Изначально никаких специализаций не инстанцируется. Для компоновки объектных файлов используется prelinker, который впоследствии вызывает компоновщик и начинает проверять ошибки. Если ошибка связана с отсутствием определения для инстанцирования специализации, будет вызыван компилятор для генерации последних.

Так же Вы можете посмотреть секцию *Notes* [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases):

> Some compilers don't implement instantiation units (also known as template repositories or template registries) and simply compile each template instantiation at Phase 7, storing the code in the object file where it is implicitly or explicitly requested, and then the linker collapses these compiled instantiations into one at Phase 9.

Answer (score 1):

1. Да, правильно. Во время компиляции в всех единицах трансляции инстанцирования делаются независимо и с потенциальным дублированием одних и тех же инстанцирований между единицами трансляции.

   Однако нет такого понятия как "инстанцирование класса". Из "материальных" сущностей в классе есть только методы и статические данные. "Инстанцирование класса" сводится к инстанцированию его методов и его статических данных. При этом каждый метод класса фактически является независимым шаблоном, т.е. каждый метод инстанцируется индивидуально, только если он фактически используется. Набор инстанцированных методов может различаться в разных единицах трансляции. Это, разумеется, в общем случае приведет к дублированию некоторых (или всех) методов.

   Предотвратить такое независимое инстанцирование и, следовательно, дублирование можно только если выполнить явное (ручное) инстанцирование таких сущностей в одной из единиц трансляции и дополнительно объявить эти явные инстанцирования через `extern` (новая возможность C++11).
2. Если речь идет о сущностях с внешним связыванием, то шаблон не имеет права порождать различный код в разных единицах трансляции. Это явно запрещено стандартом, т.е. программа при нарушении этого требования будет являться некорректной. Понятно, что компилятор не в состоянии отследить нарушения таких требований, поэтому для них обычно не требуется диагностики. Следить за соблюдением таких требований - обязанность автора кода. Иначе поведение будет не определено.
3. Разумеется, может. И не просто "может", а обязан. В этом вся идея и заключается. Линкер обязан устранить все символы с одинаковыми именами, оставляя только один экземпляр для каждого внешнего имени. Точно так же обрабатываются, например, inline-функции и inline-переменные, так что ничего специфичного именно для шаблонов здесь нет.

   Чтобы множественные определения таких символов не приводили к ошибке линковки, они помечаются специальным образом (как "слабые" символы).